# How to implement different behaviors for multiple observers?

Tags: java, android, generics, interface, rx-java

I need to give different behaviors to the method `@Override onNext()` of the class **io.reactivex.Observer** for 2 types of elements that the observer expects to observe, be the classes `B` and`C`.

```
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

public class A implements Observer<B>, Observer<C> {

}
```

When performing the implementation of the Android studio methods it shows onNext() as: `onNext(t:T):void`

[image]

But when the methods are implemented the method is `onNext(B b){}`.

And then the following error is shown:

> Duplicate class: 'io.reactivex.Observer'

Also, if I create interfaces with custom observers to implement the behaviors implicitly, I still get the same error but more descriptive:

```
public interface InterfaceB extends Observer<B> {}
public interface InterfaceC extends Observer<C> {}
public class A implements InterfaceB, InterfaceC {}
```

> 'io.reactivex.Observer' cannot be inherited with different type arguments: 'B' and 'C'.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating interface `C` that both `A` and `B` implement `C` interface and create a class that is an observer of `C` interface?

```
public class A implements C {}
public class B implements C {}

public class D implements Observer<C> {

  @Override
  public onNext(C next) {
     if (c instanceof A) {
       // ... do whatever you want to do with A instance
     } else if (c instanceof B) {
       // ... do whatever you want to do with B instance
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ITDevelopers If these classes have nothing in common, the interface can be empty.